# What are the default Credentials on a Hardened Umbraco instance on Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-virtual-machine

I created a Hardened Umbraco instance in Azure. Everything set up super smooth. I created the VM and was able to get RDP'd into it. I can also see the intro page to Umbraco when i go to the web address.

However it is prompting for credentials, which I don't think I was provided or created. What is the default username and password for Umbraco or how do I reset it?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of credentials.

- There are credentials which you gave - these are the RDP credentials.
- There are pre-installed credentials for the MySQL on the VM, these are described on the following page: http://secureanycloud.com/umbraco-technical-support-cloud-help-azure-aws-opensource-cognosys/#more-2539 (which is located on the hardened Umbraco creation wizard first page!)
- there are credential which you should give as part of your first step in installing Umbraco (you most probably talk about those credentials).

In general, you should carefully read all the screens and messages you get.